# Android: (...)Fragment class and (...)ViewModel class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am relatively new to the android environment. I had a project created from the template. In this project I worked a lot with fragments. For each fragment a class named [...]Fragment.java and [...]ViewModel.java was created. What are the individual classes responsible for. What goes into the first, what goes into the second?

First class:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
        homeViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<String> mText;

    public HomeViewModel() {
        mText = new MutableLiveData<>();
        mText.setValue("This is home fragment");
    }

    public LiveData<String> getText() {
        return mText;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Fragment** class is responsible to hold UI-related elements like `TextView`, `Button` etc. whereas **ViewModel** class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman Many thanks for the answer. However, I am not yet clear what is meant by "UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way".

Comment: Your viewmodel should "prepare"/"transform" the "data" that would be used to populate your widgets such as TextView. I've put double quotes because any business logic should be delegated outside of your view model. Once the delegated work is done, the view model should prepare the result on how the view (Fragment) needs them to.

Answer (score 1):

fragment is your view controller, it controls the view, knows when a button clicked, or where a text is placed, or a user has typed into an edit text or not.

viewModel is responsible for the logic and data of your app for example what to do when a button is clicked, or what should a textView show. when a button is clicked fragment calls the viewModel to do the proper action.
the view(your fragment) should not be able to change the properties in your viewModel it should be able to just observe them, for this we use LiveData.

they are all part of an architecture called MVVM, short for Model, View, View-Model
lookup MVVM for more information

[Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

also, this udacity course can help you a lot

[Developing Android Apps with Kotlin](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012)